# Saving a V2012 project to a different SVN repository?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a project in VS2012 that used to be maintained on a dedicated SVN server. This server no longer exists and now I would like to commit the project to my local SVN repository.

I have Visual SVN and Tortise SVN tools installed on my machine.

How do I go about switching my SVN repository location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. It is for 2010 but I think from looking at my 2012 installation that the procedure is close
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181375(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It refers to the source control menu in file but I'm not seeing that in my installation of VS2012

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVN `relocated`. Avalible via TortoiseSVN context menu.
Just specify the new repositorypath and commit.

[image]

Comment: I have the latest version of TortiseSVN installed but am not seeing the "relocate" menu choice after "export".